# High variability loss of neural networks

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm getting really high variability in both the accuracy and loss between each epoch, as high as 10%. It happens to my accuracy all the time, and my loss when I start adding in dropout. However I really need the dropout, any ideas on how to smooth it out?[image]

Comment: Are you measuring the accuracy on a batch or on the whole train & validation dataset? It looks like you're using a batch (that's not completely right)

Comment: Yep ! and if you can I would go for bigger batches... most optimization methods are sotchastic... But if you increase the batch size, the variance should be lower... I think

Comment: Yeah sorry should have put a disclaimer that I'm dealing with a pretty limited data set, ~500 samples so I'm just using the whole thing anyways. I'll work on expanding it, but at most I think is that I will get it to ~1000 samples. So still quite small

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say anything concrete without knowing what you do. But because you mentioned that your dataset is very small: 500 samples, I say that your 10% performance jumps are not surprising. Still a few ideas:

- definitely use a bigger dataset if you can. If it is not possible to collect a bigger dataset, try to augment whatever you have.
- try a smaller dropout and see how it goes, try different regularizers (dropout is not the only option)
- you data is small, you can afford to run more than 200 iterations
- see how your model performs on the test set, it is possible that it just severely overfitted the data

Comment: Hi,
Yeah I'm starting to think it's definitely the data size. Smaller or no dropout reduces the variability however results in overfitting. Should follow the golden rule, dataset size is king. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: @DavidArmstrong it is just that with 500 samples you easily overfit with almost any NN.

Comment: Yeah, working with such a small dataset I have taken a number of precautions against this (earlystopping, high % dropout etc). It's a pretty unique dataset with high variability, a basic SVM can get an MCC of ~0.5. But this is a problem that I'm interested in and one that doesn't seem to have a set answer, what's the smallest dataset you can use. I've seen examples published in biomedical literature of sizes over 200, that seems quite small and I imagine people from a computer science background would have very different views on.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that the data set is very small, during a training with a dropout regularization the loss function is not anymore well defined and I presume the accuracy is also biased. Therefore any tracked metric should be assessed without dropout. It seams that keras does not switch it off while calculating the accuracy during training.